# deleting xml child from a parent with lxml

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I am using lxml to modify an xml. In the following code, I want to delete the child of all "heading" element and assign the child text to its parent.

originally

```
<heading><whateverchildvalue>TEXTIWANT</whateverchildvalue></heading>
```

to

```
<heading>TEXTIWANT</heading>)
```

I tried to use loop for this, however somehow when I call node.remove(attr_children[0]), it jumps out of the loop and proceed to the next call of "ET.tostring(parsed)" (?) and did not modify the second "heading". To understand this, remove the "node.remove(attr_children[0])" and re-run the following code and compare the previous version of what was printed. What am I doing wrong here so that it can do a proper loop, and assign the child text to "heading" parent for all "heading" element in the xml string ?

```
xml_string="""
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<mybigheader>
    <heading><deleteme>Jani</deleteme></heading>
    <heading><wantkey>Reminder</wantkey></heading>
</mybigheader>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
"""


def modif_xml(xml_string):

    parsed = ET.fromstring(xml_string)
    for node in parsed.iter():
        print "node is ", node
        if "heading" in node.tag:
             attr_children =  node.getchildren()
             for i in attr_children:
                 child_tag = i.tag
                 child_value = i.text
             node.remove(attr_children[0])
             node.text = child_value

    my_xml = ET.tostring(parsed)
    root = ET.XML(my_xml)
    print ET.tostring(root, pretty_print=True)


modif_xml(xml_string)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/), the special-purpose declarative language used to transform XML files. Python's lxml module can run XSLT 1.0 scripts. While this may seem overkill, you avoid any `for` looping and `if` logic. Also, XSLT scripts *are* XML files and can be handled like any XML: parsed from string or file.

Specially below you run the [Identity Transform](http://www.usingxml.com/Transforms/XslIdentity) (to copy document as is), then re-write the template of heading's children by calling `apply-templates` with no `xsl:copy` (that avoids the current node):

```
import lxml.etree as et

xml_string="""
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<mybigheader>
    <heading><deleteme>Jani</deleteme></heading>
    <heading><wantkey>Reminder</wantkey></heading>
</mybigheader>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
"""    
dom = et.fromstring(xml_string)

xsl_string='''
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" method="xml"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- Identity Transform -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>  

  <xsl:template match="heading/*">
     <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
'''    
xslt = et.fromstring(xsl_string)

transform = et.XSLT(xslt)
newdom = transform(dom)

print(newdom)

# <?xml version="1.0"?>
# <note>
#   <to>Tove</to>
#   <mybigheader>
#     <heading>Jani</heading>
#     <heading>Reminder</heading>
#   </mybigheader>
#   <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
# </note>
```